# MacBook Pro 2016 SSD and Batter Life time

Tags: ssd, battery, macbook-pro

**SSD**

I have MacBook Pro late 2016 model with 2 TB SSD. I am concerned about SSDs life. I did some search and found some useful information like

- SSD will last minimum 10 years
- And Daily usage (read/write) is the second most important life factor

In my normal usage, the SSD used upto 2 TB per week. (wow, [last week stat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUaAq.png) is about 3 TB, check screenshot)

And as life cycles is the biggest life factor so I want to know:

- How long my MacBook SSD will last? (according to my current normal usage)
- Any way to optimize/reduce daily usage?

**Some Facts**

- Most data was written by `kernal_task` and `launchd` process (1,018.89 GB and 72.47 GB respectively)
- Most data was read by `Safari`, `kernal_task` and `WindowServer` process (41.21 GB, 33.37 GB and 25.13 GB respectively)
- I use windows 10 as VM in Parallels Desktop **regularly**.
- And **sometime** I do video editing and rendering in After Effect
- Other than that, there is normal usage like browsing and video playing etc

**Battery**

[Apple Claims 1000 complete life cycles for MacBook](https://www.apple.com/batteries/service-and-recycling/) And according to my current usage the rough calculation indicates that I would need to replace battery in 2 years. If I keep MAC plugged in while using,

- will it extend lifespan?
- Is this wrong to keep it always plugged in OR will it cause any battery issue?

PS: Maybe some of you think, why am I worried about all this stuff now? Well, I spent a lot of $$$ and I do care about my MAC and want to extend it's life with better usage.

Comment: Typically SSDs can withstand several thousand rewrites, so if you rewrite the SSD every week, that's still several thousands weeks.  See [here](http://www.storagesearch.com/ssdmyths-endurance.html) for some information.

Comment: Is this wrong to keep it always plugged in OR will it cause any battery issue? Yes, keeping the charger connected always will spoil the battery. Charge fully and drain the battery till warning this will give good life to your battery cells.

Comment: thank you xenoid, the article was helpful and it seems. I don't need to worry about SSD life time. And vembutech, you are right and that's correct for most of today's laptops. However, it is false for MacBook Pro because when battery is fully charged. The MacBook uses Power Adapter directly and don't interfere battery. Whereas, in normal laptops the battery is used as power source and the power adapter keep charging battery. (I am not 100% sure about this but I red somewhere) Still looking for exact or approximate answers...